# How to setup a routing to another network from a computer which is attached to network with /32 mask

Tags: linux, networking, centos, linux-networking

I have two CentOS 8 servers in a cloud and laptop connected via vpn.

First one is vpn server.

```
ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens10 proto static 
10.0.0.1 dev ens10 scope link 
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link metric 100 
192.168.200.0/24 dev tun7 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.200.1
```

```
ip -4 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.2/32 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 67739sec preferred_lft 67739sec
3: ens10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.3/32 brd 10.0.0.3 scope global dynamic ens10
       valid_lft 67800sec preferred_lft 67800sec
13: tun7: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.200.1/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global tun7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 209K packets, 57M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   16   960 ACCEPT     all  --  tun7   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/16          
    3   252 ACCEPT     all  --  tun7   *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.200.0/24     

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 937 packets, 56220 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   252 ACCEPT     all  --  *      tun7    10.0.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   20  1272 ACCEPT     all  --  tun7   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/16          
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      tun7    192.168.200.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun7   *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.200.0/24     

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 195K packets, 60M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    6   528 ACCEPT     all  --  *      tun7    10.0.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0            
  659 57980 ACCEPT     all  --  *      tun7    192.168.200.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
```

Second one is inernal web server exposed at 10.0.0.2:80

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp7s0 proto static 
10.0.0.1 dev enp7s0 scope link 
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link metric 100
```

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.3/32 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 82616sec preferred_lft 82616sec
3: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.2/32 brd 10.0.0.2 scope global dynamic enp7s0
       valid_lft 82677sec preferred_lft 82677sec
```

Laptop

```
ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp67s0f0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.0.0.0/16 via 192.168.200.1 dev tun0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp67s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.16 metric 100 
192.168.200.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.200.6
```

Networks

192.168.1.0/24 is managed by cloud hosting. It's public network.
10.0.0.0/16 is managed by cloud hosting. It's network between containers.
182.168.200.0/24 is vpn and I manage it.
192.168.0.0/24 is my home network

I can't figure out how to setup routing between computers so I can access webpage from my laptop.

As far as I understand the issue is from my web server missing a route to a vpn one. But if I try  to set a route as

```
ip route add 192.168.200.0/24 via 10.0.0.3
```

it fails since 10.0.0.3 is not in the same network as 10.0.0.2 becuse of /32 mask.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to the cloud provider to add route `192.168.200.0/24 via 10.0.0.3` into the container network configuration.

On the webserwer add the route `192.168.200.0/24 via 10.0.0.1`.